# temporal instantiation of workout function

Tags: starting-strength, timing

I have been contemplating my daily routine algorithm as of lately..

When should I call my workout function on $self?  Before I call my daily work method?  Or after I finish this method call?

What is best and why?

Comment: This question seems far too broad. Different people peak at different times during the day. With 0 information to go on, a good answer will state exactly this, but in so many words.

Comment: It's also better if you try to avoid the cute programming allegories and just ask a straight question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While some studies have been done on peak athlete performance depending on the time of day - I have yet to see a study that would prove any significant difference between exercising in the morning or in the afternoon/evening - if that's what you're asking. :)

So for what it's worth - I can only answer your question from a psychological perspective...and tell you that the best time of day for your exercise sessions would be at a time of day you're most likely to actually do it. :)

Because you can find a whole lot of people who feel incredibly energized at 5am on one side of the spectrum - or you can find people who regularly visit the gym at 8pm...so figure out what works best for you and stick to it...